# How to avoid nested ternary operators

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ternary-operator

Here is my code which is repeating pretty often, and I would like to avoid this:

```
{ isDataLoading ? (
            <MyLoadingComponent />
            ) : !products ? (
            <ThereIsNoDataComponent />
        ) : ( <div>Some text</div> )
    }
```

How could I write this to avoid nested ternary operators?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Do you want to make it more readable or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Extract each "nest" into its own return function?

Comment: @Chris Simply I don't like nested ternary operators here, I would like to avoid them, any way would be great..

Comment: @Malcor how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make an IIFE:

```
{
(() => {
  if (isDataLoading) return (<MyLoadingComponent />);
  if (!products) return (<ThereIsNoDataComponent />);
  return (<div>Some text</div>);
})()
}
```

Or, if you want to avoid re-creating the function every time:

```
const render = (isDataLoading, products) => {
  if (isDataLoading) return (<MyLoadingComponent />);
  if (!products) return (<ThereIsNoDataComponent />);
  return (<div>Some text</div>);
};
```

and

```
{ render(isDataLoading, products) }
```

Comment: Why not define the function outside rather than recreating it on each render?

Comment: A bit cluttered but I also like this approach, looks better than nested ternary operators!

Comment: @Chris It'd depend on the scope of `isDataLoading` or `products`, which isn't present in the question, I guess a named function could be called with them

Comment: @CertainPerformance they would almost certainly be either a state or a prop because otherwise there is no way to update the React component following a mutation.

Comment: @CertainPerformance the code for avoiding re-creating the function only applies to class components. In functional components world, you will still get new function every time because rendered components won't be memoized by default. "useMemo" hook or "React.memo(...)" could be used to fix that.

Answer (score 4):

You could wrap the logic in a function and call it from your `jsx` block

```
const render = () =>{
    if(isDataLoading) return <MyLoadingComponent />
    if(!products) return  <ThereIsNoDataComponent />
    return <div>Some text</div>
}

return render()
```

Answer (score 3):

This case seems like a pattern that could happen more than once in application, so it might be worth implementing another component for handling this logic, e.g.

```js
<Loader isLoading={isDataLoading} hasData={!!products} >
   <Products product={products} />
</Loader>
```

Loader component would render child components only if there is data and it is not loading, it would show placeholder message otherwise.

There is an example https://codepen.io/wilski-micha/pen/bGGbewm

Comment: Wasn't me, but I think you should clarify how Loader looks. It isn't clear how the ternary clutter is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this custom helper:

```js
const switchTrue = (object) => {
  const { default: defaultValue, ...rest } = object;
  const obj = { default: defaultValue, ...rest };
  const result = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return {
      ...acc,
      [cur === 'default' ? 'true' : cur]: obj[cur],
    };
  }, {});
  return result['true'];
};

const isDataLoading = false;
const products = false;
const component = switchTrue({
  [`${Boolean(isDataLoading)}`]: '<MyLoadingComponent />',
  [`${!products}`]: '<ThereIsNoDataComponent />',
  default: '<div>Some text</div>',
});

console.log(component) // <ThereIsNoDataComponent />
```